# yum search for 'libcli-dev' on Centos 6.4

Tags: yum, centos6

I'm compiling a 32bit binary (-m32) on Centos6.4 (64 bit). But yum couldn't find 'libcli-dev' for both of i386, i686 or x86. Which repo I should include to get Yum get these packages?

Answer (score 0):

I loaded them manually through 'rpm':

I got them from:

http://pkgs.repoforge.org/libcli/

But I still would like to know the correct repo. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

RepoForge [formerly RPMForge] has it:
http://repoforge.org/use/

```
$ wget <url>
$ sudo rpm -ivh rpmforge-release-*.rpm
$ sudo yum update
```